# R How to pass inputs to setorder in a function

Tags: r, function, data.table

I want to pass inputs to setorder in a function. Ideally I'd like the function to take a data table name and a variable name in the data table, reorder the table based on the variable, and then do some other things.

Here's an example of what I want to do that doesn't work.

```
dt <- data.table(replicate(10,sample(0:100,1000,rep=TRUE)))
sortFunction <- function(dt,var) {
     v2 <- deparse(substitute(var))
     data.table::setorder(dt,v2)
     return(dt)
}

sortFunction(dt, var = "V1")
```

Ideally, I'd like to have the function recognize that a character variable `dt` is a data table in the global environment; i.e. both `dt` and `var` would be passed as character variables and then be recognized as a data table and an

Comment: There is also `setorderv` so you can do `setorderv(dt, "V2")` and avoid the `deparse(substitute(...`

Comment: This suggestion solves the first problem. The code `sortFunction <- function(dt,var) {
data.table::setorderv(dt,var) 
  return(dt)
}

sortFunction(dt, var = "V2")` does what I wanted. What about passing the name of the dt into the function instead of the dt itself?

Comment: I really don't recommend it, but you could do `f <- function(dt,var) {tmp <- get(dt,envir=.GlobalEnv); setorderv(tmp,var); tmp}` or something similar.

Comment: A better solution for my problem is to continue passing the dt into the function, and use deparse(substitute(dt)) to get the name of the data table. However, nice to have the 'get' approach you proposed.

Comment: If you want to refer to a data.table by name I would advice to keep your data.tables (generally any other data type) in a new environment, instead of `.GlobalEnv`. Also, you can self answer your question or delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up doing.

- Continue to pass the data table in rather than try to access it via
  get(dt,envir=.GlobalEnv.
- Used setorderv with the data table and the character name of the
  column, because setorderv wants a column names/ column names as
  character variables.
- Although this isn't in the question, what I was trying to do was some
  graphs from within the function. I figured out how to put a series of plots in the j field of
  the data table.

Here's the complete function as it currently stands. I post it without a full explanation because it would have been useful to me to have this code snippet before I posted this question.

```
deltaPlot <- function(dt, var, title, ylabel, regions) {
  if (missing(regions)) {regions <- 156}
  dt.temp <- data.table::copy(dt)
  data.table::setorderv(dt.temp, var)
  junk <- dt.temp[,{
    plot(x = get(var), type = "s", main = title,
                 ylab = ylabel,
                 xlab = "",
                 xaxt = "n",
                 cex.lab = 0.8, mgp = c(2.5, 1, 0),
                 yaxs = "r")
    abline(h = 0)
    axis(1, at = 1:regions, labels = region_code.IMPACT159, cex.axis = 0.5)}
    ]
}
```

Both the string contained in var and region_code.IMPACT159 are columns in dt. The var column is numeric and region_code.IMPACT159 is character.

```
deltaPlot(dt = dt.budgetShare.wide,
          var = "delta.SSP1", title = "Delta SSP1",
          ylabel = "Change in IMPACT commodity\nshare of per capita GDP (%)"
)
```

And the output.
[image: Plot generated by function above]